# Update an image in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to update user image but it's not getting updated.

I tried with `$request->hasFile('image')` but when I return these statement it always returns false

here is my controller

```
    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $file->move(public_path().'/image/',$file->getClientOriginalName());
        $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        DB::table('settings')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->update(['logo' => $file_name]);
    }
```

when I write

```
return response()->json($request->hasFile('image'));
```

it will return always false

Comment: Try with `dd($request->image)` before `if`.

Comment: it dosen't work.

Comment: Are you sure to send file correctly from form? (multipart/form-data)

Comment: yes. When I insert image it will successfully stored.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?@Gopi

Comment: Also you have mistake on `public_path()` path goes inside brackets. [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-public-path)

Comment: What happens if you add `dd($request->files)`?

Comment: do you have enctype='multipart/form-data' on the form tag?

Comment: can you dd($request->all()); Your code should be working, i think the issue comes from the FE side. Would be nice if you can provide us with the FE code as well or if you are using postman with a printscreen of your postman screen.

Comment: @mare96 seems to be right. Are you sure you are adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form tag.

Answer (score 0):

try use this one instead

```
if ($request->file('image')) {
    // your image upload code here
}
```

Comment: `hasFile` is [explicitly recommended by the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#files). [Its implementation](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/cf907746b7f509a1e684467d95a1c04c265f603f/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L339) already uses `$request->file` internally, as well.

Comment: Yes. But why use hasFile which has more codes when u essentially just want to check for one file instead? it is more direct to just check the request file itself. The hasFile function is used for convenience but not a must.

Comment: My point is that given `hasFile` uses `file` internally, your "try this one instead" is pointless - it'll fail in both cases. There's no reason to believe your answer will fix OP's issue.

Comment: Nope. I've encountered same problem as the question above. It probably failed at validation. In my case, the file/photo is valid but it still return false which is why i skipped it because I already have my own validation. Cheers.